# Is there any predefined way to get alphabets by supplying integers in Android..?

Tags: java, android

I am having a requirement like,

if i supply 1 it should return A

if i supply 26 it should return Z

I can do that programmatically by writing my own method.

But i want to know is there any predefined method is there in andorid/java or not...?

Thanks in advance....!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
public static char getAlphaCharacter(int input) {
    // TODO: Validate that input is in the range 1-26
    return (char) ('A' - 1 + input);
}
```

I don't know of anything within Android already, but it's a pretty trivial method, so I think I'd probably go with that rather than looking for anything pre-supplied...

Comment: Jon Jon Jon...everywhere there is Jon. :)

Answer (score 1):

We have another method for Java/ Android

in `Character` class `public static char forDigit (int digit, int radix)` does the same.

example :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {      
            Log.i("MyTest", "i =  " + i + " And character value is : "  + Character.forDigit(i + 9, 36));
        }
```

your method can be

```
public static char getAlphaCharacter(int input) {
    // TODO: Validate that input is in the range 1-26
    return Character.forDigit(input + 9, 36);
}
```

Reference :  [forDigit (int digit, int radix)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29)